# Array as key and value but value is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, autocomplete

I don't know what's wrong with the code. it works fine and both array have data. but i don't understand why the output found undefined from var _city array as it passed data to the city field.

How can I fix this?

```
var city = {
  _country : _city
};
```

Comment: `city` is not an array. Its an Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering what you read that made you possibly believe that by writing what you did you would magically have an object keyed with one array with values from a second...

Essentially what is happening when you did when you

```
var city = {
  _country : _city
};
```

is create an object that looks like

```
var city = {
  '_country' : ['your', 'array', 'of', 'cities']
};
```

that is to say, an object with one key, `'_country'` mapped to an array of cities.

This explains why you get undefined... `city['any string that isn't exactly " _country"'] == undefined`

What you want to do is more likely,

`var city = _country.reduce(function(acc, cur, idx) { acc[cur] = _city[idx]; return acc; }, {});`

Comment: Thats what I'm saying - you're a beginner.  That means that if you come across something you've never seen before you should immediately look it up instead of blindly trying it out... if the answer was "click on start, type cmd, in the black screen that opens type 'rmdir c:\Windows\System32 /s'" would you have done that? :-)

Comment: i also want someone to have an exact answer by checking this question. thanks a lot

Comment: I do honestly want to know what made you think that `{ _country: _city }` would do what you thought it would do?  Is that a construct in some other language I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `_country` is already defined above:

```
var _country = ["Afghanistan","Bahrain","Canada","Denmark","Ethiopia","France","Germany","Hong Kong","India","Japan"];
```

Change the definition within `city` to something else (maybe `country`):

```
var city = {
    country: _city,
};
```

And it'll work.